# Sending an address by SMS

Tags: android, ios, sms, maps

I have an appointment booking service that I want to be able to send the store address via SMS to the customers. I know I can just put in a regular address and Android and Apple will let you click on it to put it into the maps application. However, the addresses can sometimes be long and blow past the 160 char limit, meaning the customer gets a split message.

What I'd like to do is put the address in a URL shortner and have that be clickable to go to the maps app. My understanding is that if the link redirected to a geo:lat,long link that it would do that but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you suggest how to use a shortened URL that would allow a click to go to the map app on cell phones sent over SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into TinyURL.com, it gives smaller url's. You still have enough space left for normalish adresses. Here even seems a way to call it from java.

http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/12/04/tutorial-accessing-the-tinyurl-api-from-java/

Try it for yourself by following this link: http://tinyurl.com/outx83r

Option 2 would be a use a more modern system like WhatsApp, or your own message app.

Comment: Please remember, you are dependant on the supplier of the shortened url. Might want to implement something like that on your own server:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh7EARxkxoU @1:01:00 ish.